# React problemas addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, materialize, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

estoy empezando con React y estoy haciendo una SPA de prueba. Estoy usando para maquetar materialize css y tengo en algunos componentes un event listener (por ejemplo para un modal que contiene un formulario). El problema que estoy teniendo es que, si no refresco la página, el event listener no surge efecto (no puedo cambiar entre rutas de la SPA sin que el addEventListener deje de funcionar).Dejo por aquí el componentDidMount del componente:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    
    class UserForm extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        // despues de cerrar el modal usa la función resetFormInputs
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
          var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
          M.Modal.init(elems, {
            onCloseEnd: this.resetFormInputs,
          });
        });
      }
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

amigo yo tarde  mucho en darle solucion  y no se en un futuro cause algun conflicto pero cree un una cuenta regresiva  que solo recargaba ala actualizar la pagina y se cambiaba de pestañas o target _black  ya no era invocada nuevamente  lo  que yo hize fue  en ves invocar `document.AddEventlistener` use solo la expresion en tu caso quedaria asi

```html
class UserForm extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={data:[]}
  console.log('el componente aun no carga')
}
      componentDidMount(){
     var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
          M.Modal.init(elems, {
            onCloseEnd: this.resetFormInputs,
    
  }
```

quiero creer  que la instruccion Dom contenloaded hace conflicto   con  el didmount pero igual voy empezando y no podria  asegurartelo pero yo lo solucione  asi espero te ayude